# How to configure SNMP Appender in Log4j2.xml?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

We have configured the SNMP appender as below in log4j.xml

```
<appender name="TRAP_LOG_APPENDER" class="org.apache.log4j.ext.SNMPTrapAppender">       
        <param name="ImplementationClassName" value="org.apache.log4j.ext.JoeSNMPTrapSender"/>
        <param name="EnterpriseOID" value="1.3.6.1.4.1.2854.1"/>
        <param name="ApplicationTrapOID" value="1.3.6.1.4.1.24.12.10.22.64"/>
        <param name="ManagementHost" value="127.0.0.1"/> 
        <param name="ManagementHostTrapListenPort" value="162"/> 
        <param name="LocalIPAddress" value="127.0.0.1"/> 
        <param name="LocalTrapSendPort" value="161"/> 
        <param name="GenericTrapType" value="6"/> 
        <param name="SpecificTrapType" value="12345678"/> 
        <param name="CommunityString" value="public"/> 
        <param name="ForwardStackTraceWithTrap" value="true"/> 
        <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d,%p,[%t],[%c],%m%n"/> 
        </layout> 
    </appender>
```

Since appender tag is no longer in use with the latest log4j2 version ,We need help to configure the same in log4j2.xml.Thanks!!!

Comment: I dont think there is an snmp appender available for Log4j2. Anyway I personally use an appender developed my myself to use in my projects. You can find it on https://github.com/DushmanthaBandaranayake/log4j2-snmp-appender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I dont think there is an SNMP appender available for Log4j2. Anyway I personally use following open source appender. 
You can find it on [github.com/DushmanthaBandaranayake/log4j2-snmp-appender](http://github.com/DushmanthaBandaranayake/log4j2-snmp-appender).

Comment: Thanks for the response.Actually we are using the log4j-snmp-appender.jar which internally uses the log4j jar for logging.Do we need to remove this jar for the custom implementation of SNMP appender in log4j2?I am assuming we do not have the latest log4j-snmp-appender.jar version which supports log4j2 .Please correct me if 
 I am wrong.

Comment: `log4j-snmp-appender.jar` doent work with log4j2. Beacause log4j version 1 appender architecture is little different than log4j version 2.
Therefor you need a new appender(a jar file) which supports log4j2. 
Unfortunately apache (developers of log4j) has not created inbuild snmp appender for log4j2,
I faced this problem also when Im updating from log4 to log4j2.

Comment: That is why I have created above appender. If you are using it 
you just have to checkout the code and build `log4j2-snmp-appender.jar` and replace it with `log4j-snmp-appender.jar` 
and you also need to add `1org.snmp4j.snmp4j.jar` (https://www.snmp4j.org/) into the class path. And you are also welcome to contribute :D

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response :)